# Populate each value from a text file into a text box in a html using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My Requirement is as below:

I have a web application which has Client search page(html). I have a list of Client numbers in a file. I want to pass first Client number from the file into a text box in the web url and click on submit button and wait for 10 sec to open the account details page. Once the account details page opens it should submit the return submit button from the account details page which route to account search page. Once it comes to account search page, the next value should get passed from the file and the process should follow until all the values are populated from the text file. What is the best way of doing and can I get the code for this?

Comment: Change Client to account page

Answer (score 1):

Use FileReader to access the lines of the file.

```
while (line) {
    clientSearchPage();
}
```

Use element.sendKeys(line) to input the data to the text-boxes

Use explicit waits:

```
WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element) / (ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) driver -> element.isDisplayed()
instead of Thread.sleep()
```

Make an attempt yourself before asking on SO, nobody is gonna do your job for you